# 'mapr hive odbc connector on web' throws error of compatibility

Tags: hadoop, odbc, hive

I have downloaded and installed "HIVE ODBC 64-bit connector" form  http://package.mapr.com/tools/MapR-ODBC/MapR_odbc_2.1.0_x64.exe. Since I have 64 bit m/c .

But When I try to launch “MapR Hive ODBC Connector on the web” it throws an error of “Incompatibility ”. [image]

Can anyone suggest me what could be  the issue ? how to resolved it

Comment: Please provide more details about your OS, Hive and ODBC connectors.

Comment: I am using Window-7 , Hive-0.7.1 and ODBC connectors 2.1.0 64 bit